# template parsing error - "operation not permitted"

Tags: html, google-app-engine, templates, path, go

I am developing a Google App Engine Go application and need to use some HTML templates in one of my packages. The current file structure is:

```
GOPATH/github.com/NAME/PROJECT/
                               app/
                                   app.go
                                   app.yaml
                               package/
                                       package.go
                                       Templates/
                                                 Template.html
```

To include the package, I use:

import "github.com/NAME/PROJECT/package"

Inside of package.go, I try parsing my Template.html file in various ways:

```
//Template, err := template.ParseFiles("package/Templates/Template.html") //doesn't work - "The system cannot find the path specified."
//Template, err := template.ParseFiles("github.com/NAME/PROJECT/package/Templates/Template.html") //doesn't work - "The system cannot find the path specified."
//Template, err := template.ParseFiles("Templates/Template.html") //doesn't work - "The system cannot find the path specified."
//Template, err := template.ParseFiles("/Templates/Template.html") //doesn't work - "The system cannot find the path specified."
Template, err := template.ParseFiles("../package/Templates/Template.html") //works on desktop!
```

So I take the last option that works on my desktop test environment, upload that to AppEngine and I get a new error of "operation not permitted"...

How do I parse HTML templates with such file configuration as shown above that works both on App Engine and on desktop?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the `app.yaml` at the root of your application.  App Engine uses the location of the `app.yaml` to figure out what files are associated with your application.  You want to move this file to the top-level.

For example, let's say that we have something like:

```
app.go
app.yaml
templates/t1
templates/t2
```

where *app.yaml* is what you'd normally have for your application, *app.go* is:

```
package app

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*"))

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
}

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    name := r.URL.Path[1:]    // drop the leading slash
    tmpl := templates.Lookup(name)
    if tmpl == nil {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

and `templates/t1` and `templates/t2` are appropriate template files.  Then once we have this, we can visit `t1/` and `t2/` in the resulting webapp, and it should serve and deploy fine on App Engine.

The key is to have the `app.yaml` at the toplevel directory of your application.  One other caveat to keep in mind: make sure that any files you're trying to read from your dynamic application are not statically served or skipped.  Check your `app.yaml`.  If a file is to be statically served, then usually only the front-end is allowed to see the file, which means your back-end won't.  And skipped files are just ignored altogether during deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment about statically served files - that was my issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can't read from a directory in GAE. Either you embed the Template inside a go file or you use the google Blob Storage API. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/

Comment: ... and here's an example of using go.rice to embed templates in your binary: https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/master/pkg/template/template.go#L34-L37

Comment: This is technically wrong.  See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/#Go_The_sandbox; it's perfectly legal to read files.  What's prohibited is trying to read files that aren't a part of the application.  The question presents a scenario where there's an `app/` directory, but the templates are not a subdirectory of `app/`!  Therefore, the application can't possibly access the template files because they're not a part of the application.